# Issue loading multiple "internal" links using "Telerik RadPane"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser, telerik, radpanelbar

I have an application where I have put some number of "RadPane" controls and have set the "ContentUrl" to some "internal" pages. The problem here is that they are getting loaded one after the other and not simultaneously.
I understand that there is limit to the number of browser threads. But since I'm using IE9 and there, the number of threads is 6, so at-least 6 Panes should load simultaneously, but it does not.
Things work as expected when I use external links instead of internal links.
I get the same behavior in Firefox and Chrome.

How can I make the multiple RadPanes load the URL with internal links simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer.
The issue is not with the "RadPanes" and internal links, the problem is regarding

**"Make more than one request at a time if the Session is in use"**

[Follow the link for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735107/can-a-single-asp-net-user-make-more-than-one-request-at-a-time-if-the-session-is)