# Understanding JS event loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to understand the js event loop.
This is my js code:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
var url = "/WebForm1.aspx/Test1";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Test1, elapsed: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) + 'ms');
    },
});

url = "/WebForm1.aspx/Test2";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Test2, elapsed: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) + 'ms');
    },
});

url = "/WebForm1.aspx/Test3";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Test3, elapsed: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) + 'ms');
    },
});
```

This is my server side code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Test1()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
}

[WebMethod]
public static void Test2()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

[WebMethod]
public static void Test3()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

Now the result is :

```
Test1, elapsed: 1542ms
Test3, elapsed: 4578ms
Test2, elapsed: 6636ms
```

Now what i dont understand is, why doesnt they all execute together? is it because the server side can process only one request at a time, or does it revolves with the js event loop?

Comment: looks like the server side is single threaded to me

Comment: what do you mean "looks like" :) is it single threaded or not

Comment: The ajax calls should fire off rapidly in sequence, but if the server is blocking and handling them serially, each has to wait its turn. It's server-side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428413/why-would-multiple-simultaneous-ajax-calls-to-the-same-asp-net-mvc-action-cause

Comment: So until the server side finishes one request, all other requests are stuck?

Comment: Ty stryner, that explained that to me

Comment: Have you tried this multiple times? Is the response consistent?

Comment: now you can see why I said "looks like", because ... well, it DOES appear that way

Comment: yea, thats something new i am happy to have learned, ty guys

Answer (score 2):

What this experiment shows is that the server handles the requests one-by-one, instead of in parallel. *Why* this is is not immediately apparent.

It's possible that the server is single threaded. Another possibility is that the requests require a shared (locked) resource for instance the user session or a locked database table.

Comment: as i see from @Stryner link its because it uses the same session id

Comment: Possibly, I see nothing in your code that indicates sessions are used though. Is there some wrapper code that does?

Answer (score 0):

The two arguments are **correct**. Your server can handle just one request at a time (with the same origin), and javascript has to wait for the server. Javascript anyways will execute one response at time, because it's single threaded.

Comment: _Your server can handle just one request at a time_ - **proof?** _Javascript anyways will execute one request at time_ - **no** (unless asynch=false is passed, which it is not)

Comment: Because is how asp.net works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735107/can-a-single-asp-net-user-make-more-than-one-request-at-a-time-if-the-session-is , and you are right with javascript, it could execute n requests, but responses will be handled one by one. It's more about server side.

Comment: This has nothing to do with asp.net, but with how sessions work; or locked resource in general. You see the same behaviour in PHP. If you close the session before you `sleep()`, the other requests wont need to wait.